# set maxDate as currentDate in jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I was trying to set `maxDate` as `currentDate` but unfortunately, the **year** dropdown doesn't get updated. Below is what I've.

```js
var currentDate=new Date();
var minyear=currentDate.getFullYear() - 80;
var maxyear=currentDate.getFullYear() - 1;
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange:minyear +':'+maxyear,
  showAnim:'clip'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
```

My try included adding `setDate` option with a date less than year but still dropdown value remained the `minDate` year. Below is what I tried:

```js
var currentDate=new Date();
var minyear=currentDate.getFullYear() - 80;
var maxyear=currentDate.getFullYear() - 1;
var setDates=new Date(currentDate.getMonth()+"/"+currentDate.getDate()+"/"+(currentDate.getFullYear()-1));
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange:minyear +':'+maxyear,
      showAnim:'clip',
      setDate:setDates
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
```

Any idea how I can get this done?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is about? To stop anyone choosing a future date you can simply use `maxDate: new Date()`

Comment: have you tried  minDate and  maxDate e.g.  minDate: '-80Y',
        maxDate: '-1Y',

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan.. If you run the snippet, the dropdown is pointing to 1936 and if you select any date its getting date from 2016 wherein I've set maxDate as 2015.. Hope I made it clear..

Comment: @AnilKumar I believe that doesn't make any difference. Please check my last comment.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao your snippets are working fine. You are defining the year range between `1936` (because `2016-80`) and `2015` (because `2016-1`). In the dropdown, these are the years defined. What's the problem?

Comment: select a date without changing year or month.. it will select date from 2016 @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: I see now the problem. A weird problem, I haven't got that behaviour never. Maybe a bug in that version of jquery ui?

Comment: Its the latest version available in `cdnjs` site.. @MarcosPérezGude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can restrict the range of selectable dates with the `minDate` and `maxDate` options. 
Set the beginning and end dates as actual dates `(new Date(2009, 1 - 1, 26)),` as a numeric offset from today (`-20`), or as a string of periods and units (`'+1M +10D'`).

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      minDate:'-80Y',
      maxDate:'-1Y',
      showAnim:'clip'
    });
```

Comment: Well `maxDate` worked for me but not `minDate`, and then I just kept `maxDate` with `yearRange` and it looks good now.. Thank you.. :)